# Checking a file modification date/time against one stored in memory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, last-modified

I'm looking for some help to do:

1) Get the modification date/time of a file
2) Compare against the same file after a sleep of 10 minuites and if it's **not different** to play a beep:

```
import winsound
winsound.Beep(2000,500)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [os.stat](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) is your friend

Comment: do you want a windows only solution or a cross platform one ?

Comment: You'd be much better off using a filesystem event to watch this so that you get notified immediately - Check out this page for an answer http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will be able to use below function with some modification to fit your requirements:

```
def getnewestfile(NetworkPath):
    DestFolder = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(NetworkPath)
    filelist = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    filelist = filter(lambda x: not os.path.isdir(x), filelist)
    newest = max(filelist, key=lambda x: os.stat(x).st_mtime)
    os.chdir(DestFolder)
    return newest
```

This function returns the newest file located at the network path as input.